# Java String split not returning the right values

Tags: java, parsing, string

I'm trying to parse a txt file that represents a grammar to be used in a recursive descent parser. The txt file would look something like this:

SPRIME ::= Expr eof
Expr ::= Term Expr'
Expr' ::= + Term Expr' | - Term Expr' | e

To isolate the left hand side and split the right hand side into seperate production rules, I take each line and call:

```
String[] firstSplit = line.split("::=");
String LHS = firstSplit[0];
String productionRules = firstSplit[1].split("|");
```

However, when I call the second split method, I am not returned an array of the Strings separated by the "|" character, but an array of each indiviudual character on the right hand side, including "|". So for instance, if I was parsing the Expr' rule and printed the productionRules array, it would look like this:

"+"
"Term"
"Expr'"
""
"|"

When what I really want should look like this:

- Term Expr'

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since `split` takes a regex as argument you have to escape all non-intended regex symbols.

Answer (score 72):

The parameter to `String.split()` is a *regular expression*, and the vertical bar character is special.

Try escaping it with a backslash:

```
String productionRules = firstSplit[1].split("\\|");
```

NB: two backslashes are required, since the backslash character itself is special within string literals.

Comment: or using [], like:
String productionRules = firstSplit[1].split("[|]");

Answer (score 14):

You need to escape pipe(`|`) symbol which is a `regex` `OR` operator .

```
String productionRules = firstSplit[1].split("\\|");
```

or

```
String productionRules = firstSplit[1].split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Answer (score 7):

The pipe character is the regex operator for "or".  What you want is

```
String productionRules = firstSplit[1].split("\\|");
```

which tells it to look for an actual pipe character.